# Inductive proof for the inequality

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, inequality

I would prove that $n^2<2^{n+1}$ for all natural numbers by induction proof. How ?

Comment: What are your ideas? What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm going to prove that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\ 2n+1<2^{n+1}$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

It's true for $n=1$ by direct calculation. Suppose it is true for $n$. Then
$$
(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1<2^n+2n+1
$$
where the last step uses the inductive hypothesis. Thus you need to show that
$$
2^n+2n+1<2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n.
$$
This is only true when $2n+1<2^n$, which unfortunately doesn't hold for $n=1,2$. So you'll have to check the base case for $n=2$ as well, but then you're done.

Comment: My inequality is correct. Is there any other way for this induction?

Comment: There's really only one way to do it. What I'm saying is that the inductive step only kicks in once you prove the cases of $n=1,2$ explicitly.

Comment: @IanColey: Your proof is flawless, but I point out only "$\leq$"needs to be shown in the second displayed equation since you already have "$<$" in the first (so together you still have strict inequality), right?

Comment: That's true. All the same, $\leq$ doesn't kick in until $n>2$ as well.